# Unit Tests, Inheritance and Visual studio

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I've created an abstract test base class prefixed with `[TestClass]`, that has a number of public methods prefixed with `[TestMethod]`. There are 4 classes that inherit from this base class, and each inherited class is sealed. Sometimes, one of these classes disappears from testing window. If I rerun the tests all other tests run, but that class is gone. If I manually right click next to class name - I'm able to run that test again and it pops back up in the Unit Test box.

I've never used VS2012 for testing before, so I may be missing something trivial. I'm also using resharper.

Comment: I've never heard about inheriting test classes, why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: The base class defines testing for an interface, inhereted classes modify base tests, setup and resolution to test implementation classes.

Comment: Could you point us out to an article or something to read more about this test classes inheritance?

Comment: Interesting, generally you want to avoid dependencies between tests (especially Unit tests). But I can't really comment without knowing exact set up. May be add some code samples to show how you set up the inheritance?